# How to include a git submodule into a project?

Tags: eclipse, git, namespaces, git-submodules

So I have a git repository for a few related Java classes with a folder structure similar to this:

```
mylib/LICENSE  
mylib/README  
mylib/src/file1.java  
mylib/src/file2.java  
mylib/test/tester.java  
...
```

Now, I'm creating an Android app in Eclipse with the traditional folder structure like:

```
repo/AndroidManifest.xml  
repo/bin/*****  
repo/res/*****  
repo/src/com/mysite/project/activity1.java  
...
```

Now, I'd like to add the java classes to my android project in the folder:

```
repo/src/com/mysite/mylib/file1.java
```

However, if I add it as a git submodule, they are saved to the path:

```
repo/src/com/mysite/mylib/src/file1.java
```

Also, included is the tester.java, and some other files I don't want in the Android project.

What is the best way to resolve this? Should I just leave the path as `com/mysite/mylib/src/file1.java`? Or should I modify the repo and move the files from `mylib/src` up into `mylib` and delete the files I don't want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to:

- keep your original (non-Android) repo separate
- add that original repo '`src`' folder as a source folder of your Android Eclipse project (an Eclipse project can defined several `src` folders, from various origin)

That will sidestep the "submodule" issue entirely, and allow you to select from your original project only the files you need for your Eclipse Android project.

Comment: So I added the submodule to repo/mylib, and added the repo/mylib/src as a source folder. Now, in eclipse, I have the "src" for the android project, then the mylib/src folder, and under that, "(default package)", then under that the file1.java and file2.java. However, I can't figure out how to use the file1 and file2 in the main android app since they aren't given a package name.

Comment: @user2443357 could you store `file1.java` and `file2.java` directly in their right package/directories under `mylib/src` first repo?